# Custom ABAP Code Folding in ABAP for Eclipse

Tags: visual-studio, eclipse-plugin, abap, abap-adt

I'm trying to find out if Code Folding in Eclipse is possible.
*(I dont mean the automated Folding for Source Code by the way)*

Is there something like the equivalent in Visual Studio?

```
#region Region1

 'Sample Code

#endregion
```

Would love to hear from you

Comment: you mean automated comment wrapping of Z code?

Answer (score 1):

This region feature used to exist in the ABAP editor of the ABAP Workbench (SAP GUI), but I didn't see this option in Eclipse ADT. I guess it became useless since the SAP recommendation is to write short methods.

If you really need to use regions, you may use the old ABAP editor (transaction codes `SE24`, `SE37`, `SE38`, `SE80`...) from Eclipse ADT, by first editing the ABAP code as usually, switch to the SAP GUI via the context menu *Open with > SAP GUI*, then write the regions this way:

```
"$. Region region-name followed by an optional text and a final dot.

ANY ABAP CODE

"$. Endregion region-name followed by a final dot.
```

Regions have a number of rules: their names must not contain spaces, are case-insensitive, they must not "cut" an ABAP block (like `IF...ENDIF`) in the middle, they may be nested, etc.

Comment: Okay that sounds great, my scenario is for a big CASE statement with a lot of capsuled Logic in it. I think I Try it with your approach